# Validating a transition using the new Async Ember router

Tags: ember.js

Using the non-async router, we could expect redirect on a route to be called only after resolving promises on from the model function. That's no longer the case.

How can something like this be implemented today?

```
App.ClientRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) -> 
    App.Client.findById params.client_id

  redirect: ->
    unless @modelFor 'client'
      @transitionTo 'clients'
```

Answer (score 2):

As of RC6, you would implement this like so:

```
App.ClientRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) -> 
    App.Client.findById params.client_id

  afterModel: (resolvedModel)->
    unless resolvedModel
      @transitionTo 'clients'
```

Answer (score 1):

those are two Gists from the developer of the new async router of Ember.js which will explain the new behaviour and show you some examples:

1. https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945
2. https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589

Hope they'll help you - I'm reading and following through at the moment and I think everything is really well explained ;)